# Android Studio 2.1.2 - too slow to build

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, gradle, java-8

I have dell inspiron N4010 laptop with Intel Core i5 CPU M 480 @ 2.67GHz, 4GB RAM, 500GB Hard disk running ubuntu 16.04LTS - 64bit OS. I have been developing Android Apps in Android Studio 1.5+ Version. Now migrated to Android Studio 2.1.2. Everything was smooth in previous versions of AS in my Laptop.

Building Apps in the latest version is too slow; takes 30seconds to 1.5 minutes to build - only while editing xml files. If I made any change in Java files, then build time went to 10 minutes.

So, I formatted the hard disk to ext4 and installed ubuntu 16.04(Single OS) - 500GB fully...

Downloaded and installed Android Studio 2.1.2 and Oracle jdk 8. Still it takes 10 minutes for every time I change any java files.

Here is my app(module) gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gmail.balavickey1192"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 300
        versionName "2.0"

        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "10g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.brightcove.com/releases'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'


    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.brightcove.player:exoplayer:4.8.2'
}
```

Project level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried to search from internet and found some solutions. Here is my gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx11000m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

And also disabled few plugins:

```
CVS integration
Git
Github
Google cloud tools
Subversion Integration
```

Changed following settings to checked mark by File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deplyment--->

```
Global Gradle settings- offline work
Compiler- Compile independent modules
        - Make project automatically
        - command line options: --offline --profile --parallel
        - Use in-process build
        - Configure on demand
Instant run - unchecked(disabled) everything in that tab.
```

Still it is too slow... 8 to 10 minutes!
So decided to build via command line; closed every apps even android studio, firefox and everything.

> ./gradlew assembleDebug --profile -- offline
>   first time, it said subsequent builds will be faster. Now build time decreased to 3 to 4 minutes...

Here is the report generated while building:

```
:app    6m47.94s    (total)
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug    4m7.32s     
:app:packageDebug   1m24.23s    
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders    21.533s     UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug   14.906s     
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug   10.125s     UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  9.781s  
:app:validateDebugSigning   6.251s  
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug     4.309s  
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug     3.707s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:zipalignDebug  3.657s  
:app:processDebugJavaRes    0.543s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources    0.302s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library     0.146s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library  0.121s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest   0.076s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig   0.062s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources  0.061s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72400Library  0.054s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug  0.051s  Did No Work
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library   0.050s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4141Library     0.044s  UP-TO-DATE
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug   0.041s  
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds900Library    0.041s  UP-TO-DATE

Total Build Time    7m37.73s
Startup     6.695s
Settings and BuildSrc   0.738s
Loading Projects    0.533s
Configuring Projects    10.535s
Task Execution  6m47.94s
```

Here is my system monitor screen captured while building gradle via terminal:
[image]

The same project runs smoothly on another HP Laptop with same configurations(i5, 4GB RAM, 500GB HDD, ubuntu 16.04-64 bit OS), same tools: Android Studio 2.1.2, oracle jdk-8; takes only very few seconds to build and run on that machine.

But for mine, the whole system hangs; Can't do anything while building either from Android Studio or from terminal.

Please help me guys...

Comment: I think `javaMaxHeapSize "10g"` is too large for 4GB memory. `javaMaxHeapSize "2g"`  may be fit.

Comment: Is this the only app that takes a long time to build? Did you try with other projects?

Comment: @Dalmas I created a sample application and its build time is 27 seconds only. Even If I change anything in the java files, it still takes only upto 30 seconds to build...

Comment: activate instant run, if your testing device api is above or equal to android L. it will take less than 20 seconds for successive builds

Comment: I'm testing with api level 21

Comment: @nshmura tried to build after changing to "2g". Still it is 5 minutes to 8 minutes!

Comment: If you have long delays check if there is CPU/disc/network activity. If not you have probably a network timeout problem when gradle tries to download something from a server/repository that does not answer.